# One user lands in Classic every time after logging in, all other users in Lightning

Tags: lightning-experience, salesforce-classic

This specific user has never even used Classic. The switch to go back to classic is disabled for everybody. All profiles have access to Lightning Experience. All users get a Lightning landing page after logging in, except for one user, who lands in Classic. This happens on different devices, with different browsers.

After clicking the 'Switch to Lightning Experience' button, he gets to LE. But the next time he logs in, it's Classic again.

What can cause this? The user has the same profile as many other users.

Comment: Can you check, Is there any permission set assigned to the respective user?

Comment: @AnkaiahBandi Several, but exactly the same as other users.

Comment: Can you check with user how he/she is login? If they are using to login using favorite URL then ask them to remove and login from scratch.

Answer (score -1):

We are having a somewhat similar issue.  We just enabled SSO login (using Google as ID provider) and it works, but when we log in this way, it comes up in classic UI and not Lightning.  Anyone know what setting controls this?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/195608)