Why only one user from an entire org landing on classic password change page while all other users landing on Lightning while logging in
After clicking the 'Switch to Lightning Experience' button, he gets to LE. But the next time he logs in, it's Classic again. This is happening only for one user permission sets are good and all the settings are same as the other users but only this user lands on classic always even the switch to classic is disabled still this user is landing on classic what actually needs to be checked here.
What can cause this? The user has the same profile as many other users.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000387431&type=1

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/394667/one-user-lands-in-classic-every-time-after-logging-in-all-other-users-in-lightn
